# Import statement breaks typeorm enitities when registered through config.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, koa, typeorm

Following official docs, I created small koa/typeorm/postgres app. When I was using `createConnection` with config, importing entities in the same file, app was working fine, but typeorm cli coudn't find config file so I tried moving config to "ormconfig.json". Now I get this error:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

It looks as if typeorm isn't able to use es6 features.

My `ormconfig.json`:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": ****,
  "password": ****,
  "database": ****,
  "synchronize": true,
  "entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

File with error:

```
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  ManyToOne
} from 'typeorm';
import { IsIn, IsPositive, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

import { LOAN_TYPE } from '../consts';
import { User } from './user';

@Entity('loans')
export class Loan extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  public createdAt: Date;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsPositive()
  public amount: number;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: LOAN_TYPE })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsIn(Object.values(LOAN_TYPE))
  public type: LOAN_TYPE;

  @Column({ default: false })
  public approvalStatus: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.loans)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  public user: User;
}

export default Loan;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you getting the error when trying to run the CLI, or when running the app?

You may need to change the `"entities"` entry in `ormconfig.json` to `["dist/entity/**/*.js"]` or the `"entitiesDir"` to `"dist/entity"`.

Comment: That was it, I figured it out later that night. It was confusing because I was following docs very closely.

Comment: @robfz: I was just facing the same issue, and know that the proposed solution works, but with my `synchronize: true` setting, it won't show an updated table for my entity, so I'm trying to point it to `src` since there must be issues with it on build that's showing up in the `dist` entity.

The question: is there a reason why it doesn't work with `src` path even though docs show it that way?

Comment: having to use the transpiled code in development is an abomination.

Comment: The other answer of invoking the CLI via `ts-node` seems a bit nicer: `npx ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n Init`

Answer (score 13):

1. Make sure you have `"module": "commonjs"` in `"compilerOptions"` of `tsconfig.json`
2. Run typeorm cli using ts-node: `ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js`

[See docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md#if-entities-files-are-in-typescript)

Comment: Why down vote? Accepted answer is misleading, there is no need to point configuration to `dist` directory. If your entities are in typescript you should use `ts-node` to run CLI, as  stated in the docs.

Comment: I second it. The accepted answer is misleading. this is the correct answer! Thanks, @joseph for the correct answer! You saved my time!

Comment: Totally agree too, during e2e test, it doesn't work, I had to use `https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities` to autoload entities. Because during test, it's using ts-node transpiling code on the fly (in memory) and the dist directory is not present. So at the end. best option to work in any situation

Comment: a related github issue https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3079#issuecomment-449714614

Comment: Side-note: If you don't have `ts-node` installed globally you can invoke it prefixed with `npx`, e.g.: `npx ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n Init`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is caused not just loading entities, but also for migrations and subscribers.

Your app are looking for entities, migrations and subscribers files on pre-compiled .ts files. So the files contains "imports" not understood by nodejs, it is the cause of your error.

When typescript compile the code it converts all the imports to requires (understood by node).

So to stop error at all you should make your configurations on your **ormconfig.json**:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": ****,
  "password": ****,
  "database": ****,
  "synchronize": true,
  "entities": ["dist/entity/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["dist/migration/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["dist/subscriber/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Auto-load entities](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities), that answer fits to nestJS+typeOrm.

> Manually adding entities to the entities array of the connection
> options can be tedious. In addition, referencing entities from the
> root module breaks application domain boundaries and causes leaking
> implementation details to other parts of the application. To solve
> this issue, static glob paths can be used (e.g., dist/**/*.entity{
> .ts,.js}).
>
> Note, however, that glob paths are not supported by webpack, so if you
> are building your application within a monorepo, you won't be able to
> use them. To address this issue, an alternative solution is provided.
> To automatically load entities, set the autoLoadEntities property of
> the configuration object (passed into the forRoot() method) to true,
> as shown below:
>
> ```
> import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
> import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
>
> @Module({
>   imports: [
>     TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
>       ...
>       autoLoadEntities: true,
>     }),
>   ],
> })
> export class AppModule {}
> ```

With that option specified, every entity registered through the forFeature() method will be automatically added to the entities array of the configuration object.

**And make sure that you use correct catalog path for entities dist/src.** and latest NestJs and TypeOrm ver.